# onchange event being triggered when form submits

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I would like the user to be able to record an action that they have carried out. I grouped the actions by category and then using two select menus and JS the user is only showed the actions from the category that they have selected. There is also a quantity input that is generated depending on which action is selected.

My issue is that when I submit the form, I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

The select box and the functionality implemented by the JS work until the form is submitted.

index.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  // First select 
  let cat_select = document.getElementById("id_post_cat");
  cat_select.onchange = () => handleCatChange(cat_select.value);

  // Second select
  let desc_select = document.getElementById("id_post_action");
  desc_select.onchange = () => handleDescChange(desc_select.value);
});

const handleCatChange = (cat) => {
  let quantity_div = document.getElementById("quantity_div");
  quantity_div.innerHTML = "";

  // Fetching the actions in the category selected and populating second select
  fetch(`/action/${cat}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let desc_select = document.getElementById("id_post_action");
      let optionHTML = "<option>---------</option>";

      data.actions.forEach((action) => {
        optionHTML +=
          '<option value"' + action.id + '">' + action.desc + "</option>";
      });
      desc_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

const handleDescChange = (desc) => {
  let quantity_div = document.getElementById("quantity_div");
  quantity_div.innerHTML = "";

  let time_actions = [
    "Public transport instead of driving",
    "Walk/cycle instead of drive",
  ];
  let quant_actions = [
    "Unplug unused electrical items",
    "Repurpose a waste object",
    "Use a reusable bag",
    "Buy an unpackaged item",
    "Buy a locally produced item",
    "Buy a second hand item",
    "Buy an object in bulk",
    "Use a refillable bottle/to-go mug",
    "Drink a tap beer instead of bottled beer",
  ];

  if (time_actions.includes(desc)) {
    formAdder("Distance* (km)");
  } else if (quant_actions.includes(desc)) {
    formAdder("Quantity*");
  }
};
const formAdder = (label_content) => {
  let quantity_div = document.getElementById("quantity_div");
  // Label
  let label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = `${label_content}`;
  label.setAttribute("for", "id_post_quantity");
  label.classList += "requiredField";

  // Input
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("id", "id_post_quantity");
  input.setAttribute("name", "post_quantity");
  input.setAttribute("required", "");
  input.classList += "form-control";
  quantity_div.append(label, input);
};
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def record(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.poster = request.user

            if request.POST.get('id_post_quantity'):
                post.post_quantity = request.POST.get('id_post_quantity')
            
            post.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'my_app/record.html', {
        'form': NewPostForm
    })
```

record.html

```
<form action="{% url 'record' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.post_cat|as_crispy_field}}
    {{form.post_action|as_crispy_field}}
    <div class="form-group" id="quantity_div">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Do you know which "onchange" is triggering the error? Sounds like the element you are setting it on doesn't exist. I'd start by logging the element before you set its onchange event and see which are null.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is the first select which is triggering the error. The two onchange functions are working correctly before the form is submitted. When the form is submitted for some reason, the first onchange is called again and the error saying that the first select is null occurs

Answer (score 0):

It seems the onchange was being called on every page that was loaded. That meant that, when redirecting to the index page (where the select boxes don't exist), the getElementById was returning a null value etc.

I changed this by adding conditionals to check if the elements are present on the page:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // First select
  let cat_select = document.getElementById("id_post_cat");
  if (!!cat_select) {
    cat_select.onchange = () => handleCatChange(cat_select.value);
  }

  // Second select
  let desc_select = document.getElementById("id_post_action");
  if (!!desc_select) {
    desc_select.onchange = () => handleDescChange(desc_select.value);
  }
});
```

Is there a more elegant/correct way of solving the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

for me it got fixed when i changed on submit event to btn click event.